# How to create one page but different permalink in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a problem with my wordpress website. I have one page called thankyou page. But the problem is i want to implement it to each of my contact form. For example i have contact form page named **[www.ralph-awareness.com/contact-us](http://www.ralph-awareness.com/contact-us)** and **[www.ralph-awareness.com/contact-me](http://www.ralph-awareness.com/contact-me)** . Now i want to use my thankyou page when someone fillup each of the contact form but the permalink should be like this . **[www.ralph-awareness.com/contact-us/thankyou](http://www.ralph-awareness.com/contact-us/thankyou)** and form another contact will be **[www.ralph-awareness.com/contact-me/thankyou](http://www.ralph-awareness.com/contact-me/thankyou)** . how can i do that in wordpress? It is on the permalink settings or i will modify the code to redirect it to the thankyou page. Sorry for my Bad English, Thankyouu

Comment: Check this answer - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/62846/using-custom-dynamic-slug-for-a-page . Check codex page too - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/ Another option is if information on thankyou is not too big to fit it in your contact form and after success to load thankyou info over it ?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know. You can't do it. Alternatively, you can set Thank You page globally (or for general purpose) so it can used for any purposes, but the permalink still yoursite.com/thank-you.